# angular 2 : Cannot find name 'Response'

Tags: angular, web-services, response, angular2-services

I got this error in angular 2 project :

> Cannot find name 'Response'.

the problem came from this service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class CartographyService {

  public data;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/cartography')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in the service

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```